# How to print an integer vertically?

Tags: python, printing, integer

I need the output of the code to be vertical.

```
from datetime import datetime

age = int(input("Enter your age here: "))
num = int(input("how many copies do you want? : "))

x = datetime.now()
y= (x.year - age +100)
z = str(y)

print(num * str(y))
```

Comment: do you mean in column? convert value to string and use `for` loop to display every char in new line.

Comment: try `num * (str(y)+"\n")` or `num * "\n".join(str(y))`

Comment: num * (str(y)+"\n") worked, thanks.